# Minimum Hardware Requirement for ROS

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm wondering what is the minimum hardware requirement for ROS? We are trying to build a rover with least power consumption. So we need to select the hardware which is energy efficient and can have ROS run on it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193078/minimum-hardware-requirement-for-ros/) by [qiusha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20245/qiusha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a very tough question, because it depends on which software and which ROS nodes you want to run, and how much performance you need. The "right" answer for your application could be anything from a BeagleBone to an Intel i7-based desktop, depending on what you want to use it for.

This question has been asked before on ROS Answers in various forms. You may want to review those questions and answers as well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2